# Save data from async loaded image to class member

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I want a class that saves the resolution from an image that has to be loaded first. It will print `Width = undefined`. The problem is of course that the print function is called before the callback function gets called. After I wait a decent time it will print `Width = 20`. I am also not sure if its valid to save `this` to `originalThis` and pass it to the callback function. How should the code look like so that it works without a random waiting time? I think this is a scenario where you work with Promises?

```js
class MarkerSize {
  markerWidth;
  markerHeight;

  constructor(url) {
    this.getMeta(url, this.saveData);
  }

  getMeta(url, callback) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    let originalThis = this;
    img.onload = function () {
      callback.call(originalThis, this.width, this.height);
    };
  }

  saveData(width, height) {
    this.markerWidth = width;
    this.markerHeight = height;
  }

  printSize() {
    console.log(`Width = ${this.markerWidth}`);
  }
}

let myMarker = new MarkerSize(
  'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
);
myMarker.printSize(); //prints Width = undefined
//Here, I use a timeout function to wait for the image. I know this is really bad style.
setTimeout(function () {
  myMarker.printSize(); //prints Width = 20
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Yes, using promises can definitely help with waiting for the right time to print the size, but really [you should not start asynchronous actions (like `.getMeta()`) in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572).

Comment: Thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, introducing a Promise will help solve this issue.

`printSize` method will be asynchronous and will await for `loadingPromise`.

```
  async printSize() {
    await this.loadingPromise; // wait for image to be loaded and markerWidth to be set
    console.log(`Width = ${this.markerWidth}`);
  }
```

`loadingPromise` should be created in constructor and will resolve when image has loaded.

```
  constructor(url) {
    this.loadingPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        this.getMeta(url, (w, h) => {
            this.saveData(w, h);
            resolve();
        });
    });
  }
```

Full code:

```
class MarkerSize {
  markerWidth;
  markerHeight;
  loadingPromise;

  constructor(url) {
    this.loadingPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        this.getMeta(url, (w, h) => {
            this.saveData(w, h);
            resolve();
        });
    });
  }

  getMeta(url, callback) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    let originalThis = this;
    img.onload = function () {
      callback.call(originalThis, this.width, this.height);
    };
  }

  saveData(width, height) {
    this.markerWidth = width;
    this.markerHeight = height;
  }

  async printSize() {
    await this.loadingPromise; // wait for image to be loaded and markerWidth to be set
    console.log(`Width = ${this.markerWidth}`);
  }
}

let myMarker = new MarkerSize(
  'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
);
myMarker.printSize(); //prints 'Width = 20' (asynchonously)
```

**UPDATED**
Small rewrite as suggested in comments to avoid using callbacks and creating resources in `constructor`:

```
class MarkerSize {
  url;
  size;

  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.size = null; // not loading image yet, will be loaded during first call to printSize()
  }

  getSize() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = this.url;
        img.onload = function () { // keep in mind that traditional function and arrow function handle 'this' differently
            // here this is bound to Image
            resolve({ width: this.width, height: this.height });
        };
    });
  }

  async printSize() {
    if (!this.size) { // load image if not loaded before
        this.size = await this.getSize();
    }
    console.log(`Width = ${this.size.width}`);
  }
}

let myMarker = new MarkerSize(
  'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
);
myMarker.printSize(); //prints 'Width = 20' (asynchonously)
```

Comment: Better just make `getMeta` return a promise instead of taking a callback.

Comment: Thank you for the avesome answer! :) Everything is clear but why is it possible to write `this.getMeta(... =>)` ? How does Javascript check that the function finished loading the image? In the meantime I also solved the Problem and I will post my answer here. Have a nice day!

Comment: @swftowu69 `getMeta` accepts a callback function and calls it at a later time when image has loaded. In the code above I'm creating a callback function using [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax `(w, h) => {...}`

Comment: @Vitalii you are right. I overlooked this.

Comment: @Bergi added new version of the code. Keeping the original because it's close to what swftowu69 had in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Version. What do you think is bad and what can be improved there?

**UPDATED VERSION**

```js
class MarkerSize {
  #markerWidth;
  #markerHeight;
  #url;

  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  getMeta() {
    return this.#getMetaHelper(this.url)
      .then(img => {
        this.#saveData(img.width, img.height);
        return this;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        const defaultWidthHeight = 10;
        this.#saveData(defaultWidthHeight, defaultWidthHeight);
        return this;
      });
  }

  //load img
  #getMetaHelper(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
      img.addEventListener('error', () => reject());
    });
  }

  #saveData(width, height) {
    this.markerWidth = width;
    this.markerHeight = height;
  }

  printSize() {
    console.log(`Width = ${this.markerWidth}\nHeight = ${this.markerHeight}`);
  }
}

let myMarker = new MarkerSize(
  'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
);

myMarker.getMeta().then(obj => {
  obj.printSize();
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `getMeta`! And don't forget to `reject` your promise when errors occur.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for improvement but I can't see this antipattern in my code.

Comment: There's a `new Promise(resolve => {…})` around the `this.#getMetaHelper(this.url).then(…)`  call. Just write `getMeta() { return this.#getMetaHelper(this.url).then(img => { this.#saveData(img.width, img.height); return this; }); }`

Comment: Thank you @Bergi . I will update my Code and also add error handling.

Comment: I actually meant `img.addEventListener('error', reject)`, but a timeout isn't bad either :-)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi . I will update the code. Can I catch all errors/problems that can occur with the 'error' event? I also found the 'abort' event in the internet.